# Linq Query Syntax - IQueryable ViewModel but expects just ViewModel

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Running into a bit of trouble with my Linq Query. I'm attempting to join several tables and construct a new viewmodel to return to the details page, but running into a bit of a misunderstanding or incorrect syntax.

I have a details page for loads, but I want to include associated data from the trucks table which is joined through a linking table, load_trucks. Below is what I have right now, but is clearly incorrect.

```
            var query = (from l in dbContext.Loads
                        where l.Id == id
                        join lt in dbContext.LoadTrucks on l.Id equals lt.LoadId into LoadTrucks
                        from lt in LoadTrucks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join t in dbContext.Trucks on lt.TruckId equals t.Id into Trucks
                        where Trucks.All(trk => LoadTrucks.All(ldtrk => ldtrk.TruckId == trk.Id))
                        from t in Trucks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join u in dbContext.Users on l.UserId equals u.Id into Users
                        where Users.All(usr => usr.Id == l.UserId)
                        from u in Users.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join u2 in dbContext.Users on l.CreatedBy equals u2.Id into Users2
                        from u2 in Users2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join dr in dbContext.DriverReceipts on l.Id equals dr.LoadId into DriverReceipts
                        where DriverReceipts.All(drR => drR.LoadId == l.Id)
                        from dr in DriverReceipts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join le in dbContext.LogEntries on l.Id equals le.LoadId into LogEntries
                        where LogEntries.All(lgE => lgE.LoadId == l.Id)
                        from le in LogEntries.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new LoadsViewModel()
                        {
                            Id = l.Id,
                            LoadId = l.LoadTag ?? l.Id.ToString(),
                            LoadCreatedBy = u2.FullName,
                            TruckList = Trucks.ToList(),
                            UserList = Users.ToList(),
                            DriverLogEntries = LogEntries.ToList(),
                            ReceiptList = DriverReceipts.ToList()
                        });
```

Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you can simply add navigation properties to your entities and not use explicit join query syntax at all, but instead just select the nested data directly via the entity object graph?

Comment: You make left join in your query. You should check for null in this case: `LoadCreatedBy = u2?.FullName,`

Comment: at the end of your query.... add ".FirstOrDefault();"  that should return a single LoadsViewModel instrance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add :

```
.FirstOrDefault();
```

at the end of your query.

That will effectively materialize your query to a single instance of:

```
LoadsViewModel
```

You could also wait until the last moment to call .FirstOrDefault() just before where you actually need it.